# Gnome-shell notifications in the tray gets overcrowded

Tags: 11.10, gnome, notification

The notification tray at the bottom of my desktop screen gets overcrowded with notification icons after several notify-send messages appear. Is there a way to clear this tray?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: you can right-click your icons and select "Remove" from the pop-up list:

[image: Menu entry]

Alternatively, you can left-click each one and click on its notification bubble to acknowledge and clear it.

Comment: ... I think the OP wants a way to clear all notifications all at once...

Comment: @fossfreedom Unless there's an extension that does this, I am not aware of any other way to do it out-of-the-box.

Comment: Is there a way to get Unity to automatically remove notifications from the tray after a certain period of time?

Comment: @dan AFAIK Unity already gets rid of its notifications after a couple seconds of displaying them. Unless you meant GNOME Shell...then in that case, there's no way to do it from the default install that I know of, unless there's an extension somewhere.

Comment: It's funny because it didn't do that earlier as far as I can remember. There is also an [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/41/permanent-notifications/) that specifically makes notifications permanent, which suggests notifications should not stay otherwise (/confusion/?)